# What UML Tools do you know?

Tags: uml, use-case, tool-uml

I'm designing a system and I'll use UML as Modeling, I would like that you talk about some Tools that support Diagrams UML, I Know [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com), but unfortunately it isn't a free software, I need a good tool compatible with Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no java code generation and only need an UML graphical free tool then Papyrus or Topcased is what you need. These are Eclipse plugins and are really good at graphical level because they use the GMF framework.

UMLet is also a good choice because really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

yEd Graph Editor is pretty neat and free:
http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_applicationfeatures.html

Download:
http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_download.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably this may help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Answer (score 0):

Try boUML , and it is free
[boUML](http://bouml.free.fr)

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting from scratch and do not require reverse engineering, i would recommend [Violet UML](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php)  or [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) Both have helped me greatly when modelling. Btw there is a free community version of Visual Paradigm